# Show that for $f,g \in L^{1}(G)$ we have $f*g \in L^{1}(G)$.

Tags: integration, general-topology, group-theory, measure-theory, topological-groups

Let G be a locally compact group and consider ($L^{1}(G), \|\cdot\|_{1}$) where $\|f\|_{1}=\int_{G}|f(x)|dx$ for $f \in L^{1}(G)$.

Define convolution $*$ by $(f*g)(y)=\int_{G}f(x)g(x^{-1}y)dx$ for $f,g \in L^{1}(G)$ and $y \in G$

Show that for $f,g \in L^{1}(G)$ we have $f*g \in L^{1}(G)$.

I know that this amounts to showing that $\int_{G}|(f*g)(y)|dy=\int_{G}|\int_{G}f(x)g(x^{-1}y)dx|dy<\infty$,but I really don't know how to show that this integral is finite.

Comment: Hi Chris, I would appreciate if you could undelete [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454806/calculating-distx4-e-in-mathbbrx-where-e-is-a-subspace-of-the-inner/3454831?noredirect=1#comment7102084_3454831) I think it could be useful to others

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I deleted it as the issue was just a mistake in the formula for the integrals, an issue that is very unlikely to crop up for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int |g(x^{-1}y)|dy=\int |g(y)|dy$ since you are integrating w.r.t. Haar measure. Hence, By Fubini/Tonelli Theorem we get $\int \int |g(x^{-1}y)|dy|f(x)|dx=\|f\|_1\|g\|_1$.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how the Fubini-Tonelli theorem applies in this case? I'm a little confused

Comment: @Chris $\int_G|\int_G f(x)g(x^{-1}(y) dx|dy \leq \int_G\int_G |f(x)||g(x^{-1}(y)| dxdy=\int_G\int_G |f(x)||g(x^{-1}(y)| dy dx$ by Tonelli's Theorem. . When you integrate w.r.t. $y$ $|f(x)|$ acts as a constant , so it comes out of the integral.  Hence we get $\int_G |f(x)|(\int_G|g(x^{-1}(y)| dy )dx$ and $\int_G|g(x^{-1}(y)| dy=\|g\|_1$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \int |f(x)g(x^{-1})|dxdy=^{TONELLI}\int|f(x)|(\int|g(x^{-1}y|dy)dx=||f||_1||g||_1$$

by a simple change of variables(exploiting the fact the $G$ is a group with a Haar measure)

Comment: It is crucial that you are integrating w.r.t. Haar measure.

Comment: @KaboMurphy since we are integrating over topological groups then off course you do not have to mention the haar measure,because i believe it is evident that with haar measure we integrate...i edited though for the sake of completeness